# Show that the set $ × ℤ^+$ is countable, where $=\{2,3\}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Show that the set $A  $ × $  \Bbb Z^+$  where $A=\{2,3\}$  is countable.

I checked the answer and it says that the set is infinitely countable, could someone explain why? I don't understand how this set contains an unlimited amount of integers for it to be infinite.

I also don't understand how to read this set, could someone explain what $\{2,3\}$ actually means? If that makes sense.

Comment: $\{2,3\}$ is the set having precisely the two$^1$ elements $2$ and $3$.

$^1$ I take here for granted that $2\ne 3$.

Comment: Each element of the set $A \times \mathbb{Z}$ consists of two things, first an element of $A$, so either $2$ or $3$ and second an element of $\mathbb{Z}$, that is an integer.

Comment: @UsamaGhawji Because the question is about $A\times \Bbb Z^+$, not about $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set you defined, let us call it $X=\{2,3\}\times \mathbb{Z}^+$ has elements of the form $(2,n)$ and $(3,n)$. The symbol $\times $ in the context of set theory usually means *Cartesian product* that is the set of all ordered pairs where the pairs come from the two sets you took the product of, in symbols

$$
X=\{(a,b)\mid a\in\{2,3\}, b\in\mathbb{Z}^+ \}.
$$

You can show that a set (in your case $X$) is countably infinite by finding a function $\phi:\mathbb{N}\to X$ and showing that $\phi$ is a bijection that is one-to-one and onto. In more common terms *you have to show that you can order the elements of $X$*.

In this case it would be easier to show this graphically. Imagine the elements of $X$ thought of as coordinate-pairs in a cartesian coordinate system. You can easily imagine connecting these points in the following fashion:

Start at $(2,1)$ and draw a horizontal line all the way to $(3,1)$. Next without lifting the pen draw a line to the point $(2,2)$ diagonally. You can continue by drawing a line horizontally again to the point $(3,2)$ an continue in this fashion. You will be able to reach each element of $X$ in this fashion and hence number them *first, second* and so on. This way you give this bijection $\phi$.

For an explicit definition of this bijection look at Chris Custers answer

Answer (score 4):

$\{2,3\}$ is the set consisting of two elements,  $2$ and $3$.

$\{2,3\}×\Bbb Z^+=\{2\}×\Bbb Z^+\cup \{3\}×\Bbb Z^+$ consists of all ordered pairs $(2,k)$ and $(3,l)$, where $k,l\in \Bbb Z^+$.

So, we essentially have (the union of) two copies of $\Bbb Z^+$.

But, $\Bbb Z^+$ is countably infinite.   The union of two countably infinite sets is countably infinite,  by a well-known result.

For instance,  let $\phi:\Bbb N\to \{2,3\}×\Bbb Z^+$ be given by $\phi(n)=\begin{cases}(2,k),n=2k\\(3,k),n=2k+1\end{cases}$.

Then $\phi$ is a bijection.

Comment: for this example it's pretty simple to get a map from naturals to this union set

Comment: You're right.   Perhaps I should try it.  @qwr

Comment: This way you nothing is mapped on $(3,2)$

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa $\phi (5)=(3,2)$.

Comment: ohh true! Sorry...my bad :)

Answer (score 2):

The set $\{2,3\}$ is the set containing exactly two elements. One element is $2$; one element is $3$.

$\mathbb{Z}^+$ contains infinitely many integers: $1, 2, 3, \dots$. (It's down to your course's definitions whether $0 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.)

The product $A \times \mathbb{Z}^+$ consists of all pairs $(2, n)$ and $(3, n)$ where $n$ is a positive integer. There's clearly infinitely many of them - there are two for every natural number!